# SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback vs. SSL_CTX_set_verify

Tags: callback, openssl, ssl, handshaking

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback and SSL_CTX_set_verify?
From OpenSSL docs:

> SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback() sets the verification callback function for ctx. SSL objects that are created from ctx inherit the setting valid at the time when SSL_new(3) is called.

and:

> SSL_CTX_set_verify() sets the verification flags for ctx to be mode and specifies the verify_callback function to be used. If no callback function shall be specified, the NULL pointer can be used for verify_callback.

So I'm trying to understand which callback to send for each one (from client side).

Thanks experts.

Answer (score 11):

SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback() means you're specifying a function to do the entire validation process (walking the certificate chain validating each cert in turn). [ you probably don't want to be doing this, per the warning below ]

SSL_CTX_set_verify(), on the other hand, specifies a function that's called when the default validator checks each certificate, with preverify_ok set to 0 or 1 to indicate if verification of the certificate in question worked.

From the doc for SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback()

> WARNINGS
>
> Do not mix the verification callback
>   described in this function with the
>   verify_callback function called during
>   the verification process. The latter
>   is set using the SSL_CTX_set_verify(3)
>   family of functions.
>
> Providing a complete verification
>   procedure including certificate
>   purpose settings etc is a complex
>   task. The built-in procedure is quite
>   powerful and in most cases it should
>   be sufficient to modify its behaviour
>   using the verify_callback function.

Comment: SSL_CTX_set_verify() is called only when the default validator discovers that a particular cert has failed to validate? So it willbe called only when something is not OK with the certificate?

Comment: See my answer. It will be called for client cert regardless validation result. OpenSSL passes the result to the callback in preverify_ok argument.

Comment: When you say "It will be called for client cert" - do you mean only from the server side?

Comment: Yes. All this doesn't mean much to you if you are a client.

Comment: Thanks... Some more questions:
1. Is the subject name matching validation done by the default OpenSSL's procedure? 2. Where can I get the whole list of checkings that this mechanism performs? 3. Is there a way to waive one of them specifically? (the validity date, the chain of trust, etc.) If yes - how?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback() changes the default certificate verification function. You probably should not do this. It's quite involved,  you need to check the signature for each cert, verify the chain, possibly check CRL. It's the most complicated part of the SSL.

The SSL_CTX_set_verify() is used to set the mode of SSL. If the mode is SSL_VERIFY_PEER (2-way SSL), you should also set a callback in this function to further verify the client certificate (checking CN against a white-list etc). For other modes, this CB is not used. Since you said you are in client mode, you probably don't need to worry about this call.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Does the default validation checks for subject name mismatch? I have a sample implementation that uses SSL_CTX_set_verify() in order to perform this checking. In client side.